# Api to receive payment and transfer payment

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway

I am looking for an payment api for my php/javascript based project

I googled so far for this kind of api system, I need an api to receive payments for my customers and transfer money to them from their buyer after some deduction like Freelancer.com does

Comment: You need to discuss this with your client. Ask them who their merchant service provider is, then use those APIs.

Comment: u didn't understand my question @shabs

Comment: @shabs please upvote my question if you had done it

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has an API for doing this.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/